# asp.net Web Pages / Razor WebGrid with List<dynamic> datasource, sorting issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, webgrid

When the datasource of a WebGrid is `List<dynamic>`, the sorting does not work properly. The sortdir does not switch between ASC and DESC. It's always ASC. Though, if I use a datasource of some class, like `List<SomeClass>`, then it works okay.

I'd like to use `List<dynamic>` since I am combining fields from different tables and I'd like to avoid creating additional class and looping the `List<dynamic>` result to that additional class or casting it to that class.

Sample code below to recreate the issue.

c#:

```
    List<dynamic> dynList = new List<dynamic>();

    for(int i=1; i < 11; i++)
    {
        dynamic newObj = new
        {
            Id = i
        };

        dynList.Add(newObj);
    }

    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(rowsPerPage: rowCountPerPage);
    grid.Bind(source: dynList, rowCount: totalRowCount, autoSortAndPage: false);
```

Markup:

```
<div>
     List<WebGridColumn> gridColumns = new List<WebGridColumn>();
     gridColumns.Add(new WebGridColumn() { ColumnName = "Id", Header = "Id", CanSort = true });

     @grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "tblResult" }
                    , mode: WebGridPagerModes.All
                    , numericLinksCount: 10
                    , columns: grid.Columns(gridColumns.ToArray()))
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way the WebGrid is evaluating it's datasource element type (in this case **List()** containing instances of **dynamic** objects.

Basically internally it is evaluating the element type of the list to "object" rather than a dynamic type that implements **IDynamicMetaObjectProvider** which is what it uses to then read the data source properties to figure out the column names for sorting.  Why it needs to do it this way feels like a bug with the grid to me as the sort information can probably be read from the **WebGridColumn** list.

To make this work you will still need **autoSortAndPage** but you will also need to new up the the list elements as a dynamic object that implements **IDynamicMetaObjectProvider**.  Instead of just using the **dynamic** keyword from your example, you can replace:

```
    dynamic newObj = new
    {
        Id = i
    };

    dynList.Add(newObj);
```

Instead create an instance of **System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject** to be added to your grid's data source:

```
        dynamic obj = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
        obj.Id = i;
        dynList.Add(obj);
```

You can assign the properties of the **ExpandoObject** as if it was a dynamic object. E.g the **ExpandObject** *does not* contain an **Id** property, however **obj.Id = i assignment** adds it dynamically.

If you ever get stuck on why a framework component like this does not work as expected, then you have the option to debug the framework code, e.g:

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/stepping-into-asp-net-mvc-source-code-with-visual-studio-debugger

This is what highlighted to me the issue.

Comment: It feels like it's a bug as well, since the ColumnName has been stated via WebGridColumn. Will try to adjust to use ExpandoObject rather than just plain dynamic object for future developments. Thank you for the solution and the tip.

Answer (score 1):

James commented correctly that you need to use an dynamic type that uses IDynamicMetaObjectProvider. I created a sample, was able to replicate your issue and below is the fix using type System.Dynamic.Expando.

Controller:

```
var inventoryList = new List<dynamic>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    dynamic obj = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
    obj.Id = string.Format("P10{0}", i);
    obj.Name = string.Format("{0} Testing", i);
    inventoryList.Add(obj);
}
return View(inventoryList);
```

Mark Up:

```
    @{

        var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canSort: true);
        grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);
        var gridColumns = new List<WebGridColumn>
        {
            new WebGridColumn()
            {
                ColumnName = "Id", Header = "Id", CanSort = true
            },
            new WebGridColumn()
            {
                ColumnName = "Name", Header = "Name", CanSort = true
            }
        };
    }
<div>
    @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid",
            headerStyle: "header",
            alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
            selectedRowStyle: "select",
            columns: grid.Columns(
                    gridColumns.ToArray()
                ))
```

Answer (score 0):

you are assigned  false to **autoSortAndPage** property.change this property to true